# Convert Strings of 0 & 1 into bytes

Tags: java, byte

I have two strings:

```
String a = "11111";
String b = "10001";
```

I'd like to make a bitwise comparison wih `"&"` operator.

What would be the best way to do it ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. First, convert each binary `String` into a `long` value with [`Long.parseLong(s, 2)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong-java.lang.String-int-).  This method will parse the given String using a radix of 2, meaning that it should interpret the String as binary.
2. Calculate the bitwise comparison with `&` on the two `long` values.
3. Convert that back into a binary String with [`Long.toBinaryString(i)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#toBinaryString-long-).

Here's a sample code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String a = "11111";
    String b = "10001";
    long la = Long.parseLong(a, 2);
    long lb = Long.parseLong(b, 2);
    long lc = la & lb;
    String c = Long.toBinaryString(lc);

    System.out.println(c); // prints 10001
}
```

---

Another way without using primitive `long` value would be to do it manually by looping over the digits and storing the `&` result of their code points in a `StringBuilder`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String a = "11111";
    String b = "10001";

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(a.length());
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
        sb.appendCodePoint(a.codePointAt(i) & b.codePointAt(i));
    }
    String c = sb.toString();

    System.out.println(c);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `parseLong` with a radix of 2 (you may also use the similar functions from the Byte and Integer classes, depending on the max size of you string):

```
long ba = parseLong(a, 2);
long bb = parseLong(b, 2);
long bc = ba & bb;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use either [Integer.parseInt( String s, int radix)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-int-) or [Long.parseLong( String s, int radix)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong-java.lang.String-int-).

```
String a = "11111";
String b = "10001";
int ia = Integer.parseInt( a, 2);
int ib = Integer.parseInt( b, 2 );
int c = ib & ic;
```